# How should I calculate cache miss rate of RISC-V rocket chip?

Tags: riscv

After I ran the code in the rocket chip emulator, all I got is the output log of cycles and the retired instructions. How should I get the information about total cache access and cache miss? Is there any other output files other the default one?

Answer (score 0):

No. If there is a need for these information, you should modify the source file to support some performance counters. The cache access for both hit and miss in L1 and L2 should be extracted from TileLink transactions. And then transport them to core and insert them to CSRs.